# ¿"Amarse" a alguien?

Tags: verbo-pronominal, clíticos

Una de las cosas que a mí como nativo de portugués más me confunden en el español es el uso de los pronombres, porque a veces el verbo es perfectamente cognado en las dos lenguas, pero el español le añade un uso reflexivo o pronominal que me pone perdido. Hace poco descubrí la canción Tusa, de Karol G con Nicki Minaj, en la que dice en el estribillo:

*Pero él la dejó en buzón*
*¿Será porque con otra está*
*fingiendo que a otra **se** puede amar?*

¿Qué sentido tiene ahí este **se**? ¿Se dice "amarse a alguien"? ¿Y cuál sería la diferencia sin el **se**, si hubiera dicho *fingiendo que a otra puede amar*?

En caso de que sea relevante, Karol G es de Medellín.

¡Gracias!

Comment: a otra se puede amar = otra puede ser amada. Es la misma cosa. Es impersonal.

Answer (score 1):

Te faltó darte cuenta de algo. Mira. La oración en cuestión, extraída de la oración principal y ordenada queda así:

> Se puede amar a otra.

El verbo aquí no es *amar*, ¡es ***puede***!

"Puede" es la conjugación del verbo *poder*.

"Amar" es "lo que se puede", o sea el objeto directo.

La palabra ***se*** es odiosa, gramaticalmente hablando. Se usa para muchas cosas, algunas aparentemente inútiles. Sin embargo los hablantes nativos no tenemos ningún problema con ella. Si nos ponemos creativos, alguien va a darte ejemplos de que sí es posible "amarse a alguien", en algún contexto, o jerga o en un texto específico. Pero eso no viene al caso en la canción que nos indicas. Aquí lo que se usa es la frase "***se puede***", que es muy usada y fácil de entender:

Si tratas de encontrarle el sujeto gramatical a la oración "*se puede amar a otra*" no lo vas a encontrar, porque es una oración "impersonal". Y el "*se*" en este caso es una marca de impersonalidad.

Ahora, si le quitas el "*se*" la oración dejaría de ser impersonal, y tendríamos que ser capaces de encontrar el sujeto gramatical.

> [alguien] puede amar a otra.

¿Quién es ese "alguien"? Lo tenemos en la memoria a corto plazo, es un "él" que ya fue mencionado, y que es el "protagonista" del verso.

Entonces, en  términos semánticos, en esta canción estas dos oraciones significarían casi lo mismo:

> Está fingiendo que se puede amar a otra
>
> Está fingiendo que (él) puede amar a otra

Pero extraídas de la canción, tienen significados y gramáticas muy distintas.

Answer (score 0):

- ¿Será porque con otra está fingiendo que a otra (**persona**) **se** puede amar? o (fingiendo que a otra (persona) puede amar**se**). (Habla de forma general, sin especificar. Cualquier persona puede amarse de la misma manera que la anterior).
- ¿Y cuál sería la diferencia sin el "**se**", si hubiera dicho, "fingiendo que a otra puede amar"? (fingiendo que a otra ( persona, **él**) puede amar). (Habla de forma concreta, refiriéndose a él, solo al hombre).

**Formas en las que puede encontrarse la partícula "se"**

«Se venden casas», «Se buscan actores» frente a «Se busca a los culpables»

*"El se impersonal se puede usar para generalizar. Equivale a "uno" o "la gente". No hay un sujeto (agente) específico. Suele estar acompañado de un verbo intransitivo, un verbo copulativo o con un verbo transitivo que lleva complemento directo precedido de la a personal".*

*"¿Cómo saber si el se es impersonal?
b) oraciones impersonales. Se llaman así por carecer de sujeto gramatical y en ellas la forma se precede siempre a un verbo en tercera persona del singular"*.

[https://www.rae.es/espanol-al-dia/se-venden-casas-se-buscan-actores-frente-se-busca-los-culpables#:~:text=b](https://www.rae.es/espanol-al-dia/se-venden-casas-se-buscan-actores-frente-se-busca-los-culpables#:%7E:text=b))%20oraciones%20impersonales.,en%20tercera%20persona%20del%20singular.

---

**Formas de los pronombres personales átonos**.

> Pronombres personales átonos. 1. Formas. Los pronombres personales
> átonos son aquellos que funcionan como complemento verbal no
> preposicional (Ya te lo he dicho) o como formante de los verbos
> pronominales (Ahora me arrepiento). Precisamente por su carácter
> átono, se pronuncian necesariamente ligados al verbo, con el que
> forman una unidad acentual. **Estos pronombres** carentes de independencia
> fónica **se denominan**, en general, «**clíticos**» (→ acento, 1.1b): **cuando
> anteceden al verbo** (me encanta; lo dijo; se fue) **se llaman**
> «**proclíticos**»; **cuando siguen al verbo** (ayúdame, díselo, vete) **se
> llaman** «**enclíticos**». A continuación se ofrece un cuadro con sus
> formas:

[image]

[https://www.rae.es/dpd/pronombres%20personales%20%C3%A1tonos#:~:text=Por%20lo%20tanto%2C%20los%20pronombres,%2C%20os%20espero%20en%20casa](https://www.rae.es/dpd/pronombres%20personales%20%C3%A1tonos#:%7E:text=Por%20lo%20tanto%2C%20los%20pronombres,%2C%20os%20espero%20en%20casa)).